# Is Java (byte) literal conversion efficient?

Tags: java, casting, byte, literals

Ok, as of Java 6 there is no y literal suffix.  Consider this code:

```
byte b = some_byte();
switch (b) {
    case (byte) 0x80: ...
    case (byte) 0x81: ...
```

and this alternative:

```
int b = some_byte() & 0xff;
switch (b) {
    case 0x80: ...
    case 0x81: ...
```

Which would you use?  In the first case, are (byte) casts performed during run time or compile time?  Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think this particular piece of code will have the most significant impact on the performance of your application?

Comment: @mellamokb Well, if you do it many times, **everything** can be considered significant and is worth optimizing. Especially if the change is something simple and still readable like this...

Comment: @brimborium: I agree wholeheartedly.  My point is, however, was this application profiled, or is the OP just guessing?  It's never wise to try to randomly make little blocks of code more efficient and sacrifice readability if you don't really know there's a problem there.

Comment: Just guessing... actually trying to learn proper syle from the start.  Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Which would you use?

Probably the latter, just for simplicity - but with a comment to explain what's going on.

> In the first case, are (byte) casts performed during run time or compile time?

Compile-time. Don't forget that case values have to be compile-time constants anyway.

Another option is to create constants for these things:
    private static final byte FOO = (byte) 0x80;
    private static final byte BAR = (byte) 0x81;

```
...

switch (someByte()) {
    case FOO:
    case BAR:
        ...
}
```

Aside from anything else, that makes the values less "magic".

Or you could possibly even use an enum...

Comment: +1 I doubt there is a performance difference given switch only supports `int` type for numbers in the byte code.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case,

```
some_byte() & 0xff;
```

adds 2 instructions. The rest is identical. You can check it with

```
javap -c Test
```

where Test is the name of the test class.

Comment: Thanks for the decompiler tip (too lazy to use it...)